# Is it possible to use a MongoDB aggregate query with date matching?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Im trying to get the count of certain items grouped on certain dates.
This is working using the following aggregate query:

```
// this query works, without matching dates
[
  {'$match': {
    'some_id': ObjectId('foobar'),
    'some_boolean_value': true
    }
  },
  {'$project':
    {'day':
      {'$substr': ['$some_date', 0, 10]}}
  },
  {'$group': {_id: '$day', count: { '$sum': 1 }}},
  {'$sort': {_id: -1}}
]
```

The next step is that I want to use this query but with date limits.
I want the count, grouped per day, between certain date limits.

```
 // the query below does not work as soon as date matching is added
 // this query always return 0 documents
[
  {'$match': {
    'some_id': ObjectId('foobar'),
    'some_boolean_value': true,
    'some_date':
      {
        '$gte': '2015-08-01T00:00:00.000Z',
        '$lte': '2015-08-31T23:59:59.999Z'
      }
    }
  },
  {'$project':
    {'day':
      {'$substr': ['$some_date', 0, 10]}}
  },
  {'$group': {_id: '$day', count: { '$sum': 1 }}},
  {'$sort': {_id: -1}}
]
```

Comment: You are using "strings". Do your documents contain "strings" or do they contain `Date` objects.

Comment: @BlakesSeven They contain `Date` Objects, i just filled them with actual dates as as example.

Comment: Then you don't use `$substr` on something that is not a "string". That should be pretty clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDb aggregation Group by Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950202/mongodb-aggregation-group-by-date)

Comment: You need to wrap the strings in ISODate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to filter documents and match only those in a specified datetime window. But you use string comparison instead of date comparison.

Therefore replace this:

```
'$gte': '2015-08-01T00:00:00.000Z',
'$lte': '2015-08-31T23:59:59.999Z'
```

with this:

```
'$gte': new Date('2015-08-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
'$lte': new Date('2015-08-31T23:59:59.999Z')
```

Comment: This was super useful I spent days wondering why my aggregation of sales records for the day keeps adding sales from previous days. It is because my $gte condition is comparing a string (todayBeginning) constructed in my controller to a Date object (createdAt) coming from my MongoDB. Printing the two date on node console fooled me for days thanks a lot @Mike